# Entity Framework 6.1.3 Remove Conventions Using ModelBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I use the following function to remove multiple conventions in Entity Framework 6.1.3?

```
public void Remove(
params IConvention[] conventions)
```

This is a link to the documentation, but this function doesn't seem to work?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionsconfiguration.remove%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.Remove%28System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.IConvention[]%29

I have tried:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(new PluralizingTableNameConvention());
    }
```

but this doesn't work.

Please post an example of how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```